# How is a global variable sustained when it's first deleted and then recreated inside a function?

Tags: python

I am unable to understand why the code is not showing any error when I try:

```
x = 2

def foo():
    global x
    del x
    x = 3

foo()
print(x)
```

Output: `3`

I was expecting that `del x` would delete the reference to `2` and thus, *there will not be any global variable*, keeping the reference to `3` locally (accessible only within the function and not outside it).

Can someone explain what's incorrect with my understanding of `global` and/or `del`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import dis
print(dis.dis(foo))
```

you will see the bytecode which will explain

```
  4           0 DELETE_GLOBAL            0 (x)

  5           2 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              4 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this article: [why is the del statement in Python unable to delete data referenced by variables?](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012415)

If I try to explain in words;
What happens with global x is whenever you refer to x inside the function namespace it looks for a similar name in global scope.

But del just deletes any name that is in function scope. In this case after deleting you assign x=3, which in turn trigger an assignment to global x.